# Multi Threading with ThreadPool while saving state

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, scheduledexecutorservice

Suppose I have 100 Runnable objects in Queue. If I use a ExecutorServicePool with some fixed size say 10, then atleast one of the 10 threads needs to be terminated for next Runnable object to be executed from the Queue. Is there any other way I can schedule the next Runnable from the Queue after a particular interval and save the current Runnable state to be saved at the end of the Queue somewhat like round robin fashion ?

Comment: What is your real goal? There might be a better way than the situation you're describing.

Comment: Do you mean you want to yield the thread in the pool after a certain time period if it's still running?

Comment: Threads don't need to be terminated (and aren't). One of the runnables needs to finish. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My main goal is to run all those 100 Runnable objects in the Queue, each for a fixed time even if they are not run till completion. However I need to add the current state of the runnable object to the Queue again so that the execution starts from where it was stopped earlier.

Comment: Then you'll need to split the runnables and resubmit new ones while letting the previous one finish.

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way I can schedule the next Runnable from the Queue after a particular interval and save the current Runnable state to be saved at the end of the Queue somewhat like round robin fashion ?

I hope I understand the question here.  If this isn't what you are talking about then please edit your question and give more details.

If you are talking about saving state, the easy solution would be to use a `ThreadLocal` so that each of the threads running in your executor service can save their own state.

```
private final ThreadLocal<State> stateThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>() {
   // state initialization if needed
   protected State initialValue() { return new State(); }
};
...
public void run() {
   State state = stateThreadLocal.get();
   // now you can process the job with the state
}
```

However, this solution doesn't give you opportunities to control when the state is released if you need to close a http-client or something.

A better solution may be to use the executor-service to just start a static list of workers and then use your own `BlockingQueue` to inject jobs to the workers.

For example you could do something like:

```
private final static int NUM_WORKERS = 10;
private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_WORKERS);
...

final BlockingQueue<Job> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_WORKERS; i++) {
    threadPool.submit(new WorkerWithState(queue));
}
// shutdown the queue once the last worker is submitted
threadPool.shutdown();
 ...
// then you submit a number of jobs to your own queue for the workers with state to run
queue.add(new Job(...));
...
```

Your workers would hold a local state field that they would hold between runs.

```
private class WorkerWithState implements Runnable {
   // some state held by the worker
   private SomeState state = new SomeState();
   private final BlockingQueue queue;
   public WorkerWithState(BlockingQueue queue) {
      this.queue = queue;
   }
   public void run() {
      while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
         try {
            // wait for a job to process
            Job job = queue.take();
            // process the job here using the state
            processJob(job, state);
         } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            // always a good pattern
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

To terminate these workers, you can call `threadPool.shutdownAll(true)` on the thread-pool to interrupt them all or inject a constant `QUIT_JOB` to have them stop themselves once the job queue has been exhausted.